# Example Chainlink API GET Contract Compiles but Fails at Deploy

Tags: chainlink

Hey guys attempting to test deployment of the example api get contract provided in chainlink docs. Is there a reason why

> https://docs.chain.link/docs/make-a-http-get-request/

fails to deploy?

Even when using a polygon supported oracle and job id?  Is something wrong with the v8 example contracts?  compiles fine, but cannot deploy -

> execution reverted

.

Initially I modified using it as a base example for my own version. That failed and now revisiting the original contract, this fails too. Telling me that there is an issue with this v8 example.

There are no changes to the contract in the link. Copy paste into remix and attempt to deploy to polygon main net. Execution reverted

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

need to set chainlink token and comment out constructor function of

> ```
>     setPublicChainlinkToken();
> ```